# When animating markers with R plotly why does the overplotted bars disappear

Tags: r, animation, plotly

I have a plotly bar plot with markers overplotted.
I want to animate the markers but not the bars.
As soon as the animation starts, the bars disappear.

```
library(plotly)

a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(1, 3, 2)
c <- c('first', 'second', 'third')

p <- PlotData %>% plot_ly(type='bar') %>%
  add_bars (x = a, y =  b, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_markers(x=a,y=b,frame=c)

print(p)
```

How do I stop the bars from disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to set `animation_opts()` which has a parameter `redraw` that by default is set to `TRUE`.
It is not a perfect solution, as the bars disappear during each animation transition. This can be minimised by setting `transition = 0`.

```
library(plotly)

a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(1, 3, 2)
c <- c('first', 'second', 'third')

p <- PlotData %>% plot_ly(type='bar') %>%
  add_bars (x = a, y =  b, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_markers(x=a,y=b,frame=c) %>%
  animation_opts(redraw=TRUE, transition = 0)

print(p)
```